# How to turn on specific elements inside Button-group with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, view, radio-button

I have a btn-group inside the form to select between the 7 days of the week, the method is already working for create and edit forms... but in the Get view from the Edit I need to "Turn-on" the buttons that are already coming true from the object in the controller... I tried several ways ( you will see in the code, but with no success ) This is already working, but I need to show the corresponding buttons turned on in the document.ready side...

my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
       $('#genreButtons')
            .on('click', 'button', function (event) {
                //  console.log("T:", this);
                $(this).toggleClass("we-selected");
                // console.log("T after:", this);
                // console.log('click:', $(this).text(), $(this).data('value'));
                let buttonValues = [];
                let buttonObjects = [];
                let buttons = $(event.delegateTarget).find('button');
                console.log("We have " + buttons.length + " buttons");
                let weSelectedButtons = buttons.filter('.we-selected');
                console.log("We selected " + weSelectedButtons.length + " buttons");
                weSelectedButtons
                    .each(function (index, element) {
                        buttonValues.push($(element).data('value'));
                        buttonObjects.push({
                            name: $(element).text(),
                            value: $(element).data('value')
                        });
                    });
                console.log("Values:", buttonValues);
                console.log("Objects:", buttonObjects);

                $('input[name="valueGenre"]').val(buttonValues.join(','));
                $('#debug').html(buttonValues.join(','));

                $('#DaysSelected').val(buttonValues.join(','));
                $('#DaysSelected').html(buttonValues.join(','));
                //document.getElementById("DaysSelected").value = aux;
            });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mon = document.getElementById("Monday").value;
            if (mon == "True")
            {
                //document.getElementById("genre0").buttonValues.val = true;
                document.getElementById("genre0").removeClass("active");
                document.getElementById("genre0").addClass("active");
            }

            var sun = document.getElementById("Sunday").checked; //Better
            if (sun == true)
            {
                //document.getElementById("genre0").buttonValues.val = true;
            }
        });

    </script>
```

```html
                   <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
    <form asp-action="Edit">
        <div class="row">
                   <input type="hidden" asp-for="Monday" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Tuesday" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Wednesday" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Thursday" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Friday" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Saturday" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Sunday" />


            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="ibox ">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5></h5>
                        <div class="ibox-tools">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                       <div class="btn-group d-flex w-100" id="genreButtons">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="0" name="genre0" id="genre0" type="button">Monday</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="1" name="genre1" id="genre1" type="button">Tuesday</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="2" name="genre2" id="genre2" type="button">Wednesday</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="3" name="genre3" id="genre3" type="button">Thursday</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="4" name="genre4" id="genre4" type="button">Friday</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="5" name="genre5" id="genre5" type="button">Saturday</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="6" name="genre6" id="genre6" type="button">Sunday</button>
                        </div>
                        <input name="valueGenre" value="" hidden />
                        <div id="debug" hidden></div>
                        <div class="form-group" hidden>
                            <label asp-for="DaysSelected" class="control-label col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <textarea rows="2" draggable="false" maxlength="400" asp-for="DaysSelected" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                <span asp-validation-for="DaysSelected" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-warning">Back</a>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using javascript, you should add and remove css in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mon = document.getElementById("Monday").value;
    var sun = document.getElementById("Sunday").value;
    if (mon == "True") {
        document.getElementById("genre0").classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById("genre0").classList.add("active");
    }
    if (sun == "True") {
        document.getElementById("genre6").classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById("genre6").classList.add("active");
    }
});
```